# Driving parallel MOSFETs (IRF540) with IRS2092

Tags: mosfet, audio, mosfet-driver, power-amplifier

The [IRS2092 datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1138.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559a077610d1) shows a 4 ohm load circuit (see image below).

I want to check whether MOSFETs can be paralleled to support low impedance of 2 ohms, instead of 4 ohms as shown. Can anyone please let me know whether it is feasible?

The MOSFETs I plan to use are [IRF540](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91021/91021.pdf).

[image: Typical Application Circuit]

Comment: At a first glance it *should* work. Read the AN "Paralleling Of Power MOSFETs For Higher Power Output" for the gory details and calculations involved. Also the output filter will need a tune up

Comment: Comparing the ***application specific*** (small power, Id < 10A audio etc) IRF6645 to ***general purpose*** high power (Id > 30A) amplification/switching IRF540 datasheets on the general parameters Vds, Id, Vgs(th) etc, I found IRF6645 is smaller in size, but also smaller in power, better thermal performance. So if Infeion specifies that IRF6645 can do the audio amplification job, it is very likely the IRF540N can also do the job at much higher power, but also much worst audio performance.

Comment: And in case you are doing trials and errors, I would recommend IRL540N which should preform better than IRF540N. Also the following might help: How to choose MOSFETs for Class D amplifiers - By Jorge Cerezo, International Rectifier  02.14.2006 
https://www.eetimes.com/how-to-choose-mosfets-for-class-d-amplifiers/#

Comment: Wonderfuliot, please take the [2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand what motivates people to give free advice on this site.

Answer (score 1):

It will be able to drive parallel MOSFETs because they are being used in their triode region but, take into account what the [application note](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1138.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559a077610d1) says here: -

[image]

So, if you choose two parallel MOSFETs you should ensure that the total combined gate charge does not exceed the limitations implied in the top paragraph.

You might also be sensible to track down what [AN-1070](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/an-1070.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559530600fe5) is telling you: -

[image]

Enjoy the read.